# Matlab function call in python with parameters

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, casting, correlation

I'm trying to execute the matlab function (through the Matlab engine) `corr` to calculate the correlation between two .mat files by the following code:

```
# Import of python library that handles matlab files.
import scipy.io as sio
#Matlab import to call matlab functions in python
import matlab.engine
matlab = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

mattraces = (sio.loadmat('traces.mat'))
print("loaded1")
mathamming = (sio.loadmat('hamming.mat'))
print("loaded2")

correlation = matlab.corr(mattraces, mathamming)
```

However, this code throws the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/pymat.py", line
>   13, in 
>       correlation = matlab.corr(mattraces, mathamming)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matlab\engine\matlabengine.py", line
>   79, in **call**
>       out=_stdout, err=_stderr) ValueError: invalid field for MATLAB struct

Does somebody have any idea how to correlate two .mat files by the `corr` Matlab function in `python`